# How stable are surfaces functionalized with APTES?

Tags: organic-chemistry, surface-chemistry

I'm wondering specifically about magnetite micro particles functionalized/silanated with (3-aminopropyl)triethoxysaline (APTES), though I assume the stability would be the same for most surfaces.

By stability, I mean can the APTES "fall off" the surface over time or in extreme conditions (pH, temperature, pressure, etc.)?

Comment: Silanes do not bind very well with transition metal oxides. Many people tried covalently linking titanium oxide and zirconium oxide with silanes. The results were disappointing because it would wash off soon. Ignore such junkyard papers which say that the silane was covalently bonded metal oxide. Amino silane is no exception. If the silane is polymerized around the metal nanoparticles, then it is a different story.

Comment: @M. Farooq what would the stability of APTES polymerized around iron oxide particles be?

Comment: Stability is an ill-defined term. Chemists should always mention stability with to something. Polymerized APTES will disintegrate at high pH. What is your pH range?

Comment: Good point. My pH and temperature ranges are actually reasonable: pH 5.5-7 and 30-50 C. The issue is time. I need the functionalization to remain at least 50% in tact (relative to the starting functionalization measured as mg APTES per gram support) over several months with essentially continuous liquid flow over the surface.

Comment: I think you basically want amine groups on iron oxide particles? See if polymerization works. What is your procedure for "bonding" APTES to iron oxide?

Comment: Yes; protein immobilization is the end goal here. Sonication of the APTES and particles in methanol-water at 20 khz as described in this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Aidin_Bordbar-Khiabani/post/Simple-method-for-direct-coating-of-APTES-on-surface-of-Iron-oxide-Fe2O3/attachment/5cb10d443843b01b9b99a06b/AS%3A746987641114624%401555107140026/download/wang2016.pdf

Comment: They are using the word coating and apparently the nanoparticles are formed *in the presence of APTES* so worth trying to repeat their work. In the presence of ammonia and water the silane must have polymerized.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know the silane would polymerize with ammonia and water. Does that very significantly increase the stability? Do you think it could ever remain functionalized for months, or is that a pipe dream?

Comment: I don't think so that ATPES will remain there for months. Silanes have a tendency to polymerize in the presence of water, acids or bases. My experience is limited to bonding chemistry related to silica particles. The funny thing is that silica bonded to propylamino silane hurts the silica.

Comment: Hmm... I will need to pursue a different route then. Thank you so much for your help! You've given me a lot of great information!

Comment: Good luck. Study the silica bonding literature first, search Langmuir journal as well. It did have a stability article.